# Where can the angle for Select Sharp Edges operation be set in Blender 2.80?

Tags: interface, edit-mode

Angle value for function "Select Sharp Edges" in Blender 2.79 is here:

[Select sharp edges what's the angle value](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119498/select-sharp-edges-whats-the-angle-value)

Where is it in Blender 2.80?

Comment: Please do not post the answer in your question. If you found out the answer on your own, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I found it, the panel to edit options of the last used operator in 2.8 is in the bottom of 3D viewport, by default it's minimized. Default shortcut to open it was also changed and now it is <kbd>F9</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the **header bar** > **Select** > **select shap edges**
[image]

You can also use search <kbd>F3</kbd> to find this operator
[image]

Python Script: `bpy.ops.mesh.edges_select_sharp()`